# Linkedin Company insider plugin does not work when company includes ' in it's name

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I am trying to use the LinkedIn Company Insider plugin here:

https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/company-insider-plugin-generator

but I am facing an issue if the name of the company has an "'" in it's name.

For example: James's Company

I tried encoding the ' character but no luck.

How can i encode the ' character in the middle of a name in ASCII, precisely in & #39;

Comment: Did you try a backslash? `\'`

Comment: Yes I did. I think i found the solution. Will update my question soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by using the htmlentities() function in php like below:

```
htmlentities("James's Shop", ENT_QUOTES)
```

That did the trick!